# Ошибка SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Tags: python

Ребята запутался в циклах в конце

```
user_str = input('Enter your e-mail or phone number or your full name:')
user_str = user_str.strip()
res = ''
signs = '()- '
if ('@' in user_str) and ('.' in user_str):
    raw_list = user_str.split('@')
    if len(raw_list) == 2:
        if raw_list[0].isalpha() and len(raw_list[0]) > 2:
            part_raw = raw_list[1].split('.')
            if (part_raw[0].isalpha() and len(part_raw[0]) > 2) and (
                    part_raw[1].isalpha() and len(part_raw[1]) > 2):
                res = 'Email'
elif len(user_str) == 3:
    if user_str.isalpha():
        name = user_str[0]
        scnd_name = user_str[1]
        surname = user_str[2]
        if (name[0].isupper() and len(name) > 2) and (scnd_name[0].isupper() and len(scnd_name) > 2) and (
                surname[0].isupper() and len(surname) > 2):
            res = 'full name'
else:
    for i in user_str:
        if i in signs:
            user_str = user_str.replace(i, '')
    if user_str[0] == '+' and len(user_str) == 13:
        res = 'phone'
    elif user_str[0] == '0' and len(user_str) == 10:
        res = 'phone'
    if res:
        print(f'\'{user_str}\' is {res}')
    else:
       continue
question = input('Would you like to restart (Y/N)?') # тут хотел создать цикл, что бы в случае ввода ерунды повторялся вопрос, но запутался в циклах
if question.upper() == 'Y':
       continue
elif question.upper() == 'N':
        break
else:
        continue
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, а в чем именно путаница?

Comment: выдает syntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не путаться - разделяйте код на отдельные функции, не допускайте слишком большой вложенности блоков или слишком длинных блоков кода.

В вашем случае можно просто основной код вынести в функцию, которую уже будете вызвать в цикле:

```
def main(user_str):
    res = ''
    signs = '()- '
    # и дальше ваш код из вопроса до question

while True:
    user_str = input('Enter your e-mail or phone number or your full name:')
    user_str = user_str.strip()
    # Если нужно, здесь добавляете проверки
    if ...:  # вместо ... вставьте условие
        print('Вы ввели какую-то ерунду')
        continue

    main(user_str)

    question = input('Would you like to restart (Y/N)?')
    if question.upper() == 'Y':
        continue
    elif question.upper() == 'N':
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Так вы разделите ввод данных, их проверку, обработку, повторное выполнение.

При вопросе на повторное выполнение можно вообще не делать особых проверок - если введено Y или y, то считать это согласием, все остальное считать несогласием:

```
question = input('Would you like to restart (Y/N)?')
if question.upper() == 'Y':
    continue
else:
    break
```